# How to first n rows from Parquet file in Java without downloading the entire file

Tags: java, hadoop, parquet

My requirement was to read parquet file from s3/sftp/ftp and read few rows from the file and write it to csv file.

Since I didn't find any generic solution to read parquet file directly from s3/sftp/ftp, I am downloading parquet file to my local using InputStream.

```
File tmp = null;
File parquetFile = null;
try {
      tmp = File.createTempFile("csvFile", ".csv");
      parquetFile = File.createTempFile("partquetFile",".parquet");
      
      //downloading file to local
      StreamUtils.dumpToDisk(parquetFile, feed.getInputStream());
      parquetReaderUtils.parquetReader(new 
      org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(parquetFile.getAbsolutePath()),tmp);
                
    } catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error reading parquet file.");
    }
    finally {
              FileUtils.deleteQuietly(tmp);
              FileUtils.deleteQuietly(parquetFile);
    }
```

One the file is downloaded I am calling parquetReader() method of ParquetReaderUtils class to read the file from local path. And writing first 5 rows from parquet file to csv file.

Below is the ParquetReaderUtils class definition :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.parquet.column.page.PageReadStore;
import org.apache.parquet.example.data.Group;
import org.apache.parquet.example.data.simple.convert.GroupRecordConverter;
import org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.metadata.ParquetMetadata;
import org.apache.parquet.io.ColumnIOFactory;
import org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO;
import org.apache.parquet.io.RecordReader;
import org.apache.parquet.schema.MessageType;
import org.apache.parquet.schema.PrimitiveType;
import org.apache.parquet.schema.Type;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.temporal.JulianFields;

@Component
public class ParquetReaderUtils {
    private static final String CSV_DELIMITER = ",";

// Reading parquet file from local and writing first 5 rows to csv file.
    public void parquetReader(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path path, File csvOutputFile, InputStream in) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(in);
        int headerRow = 0;
        int rowsRead = 0;
        try {
            ParquetMetadata readFooter = ParquetFileReader.readFooter(conf, path, ParquetMetadataConverter.NO_FILTER);
            MessageType schema = readFooter.getFileMetaData().getSchema();
            ParquetFileReader r = new ParquetFileReader(conf, path, readFooter);
            BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvOutputFile));
            PageReadStore pages = null;
            try {
                while (null != (pages = r.readNextRowGroup())) {
                    final long rows = pages.getRowCount();
                    System.out.println("Number of rows: " + rows);

                    final MessageColumnIO columnIO = new ColumnIOFactory().getColumnIO(schema);
                    final RecordReader recordReader = columnIO.getRecordReader(pages, new GroupRecordConverter(schema));
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                        final Group g = (Group) recordReader.read();
                        //printGroup(g);
                        writeGroup(w, g, schema, headerRow);
                        rowsRead++;
                    }
                    if(rowsRead==5)
                        break;
                }
            } finally {
                r.close();
                w.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading parquet file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

// writing rows to csv file.
    private static void writeGroup(BufferedWriter w, Group g, MessageType schema, int headerRow)
            throws IOException {
        if (headerRow < 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < schema.getFieldCount(); j++) {
                if (j > 0) {
                    w.write(CSV_DELIMITER);
                }
                Type fieldType = g.getType().getType(j);
                String fieldName = fieldType.getName();
                w.write(fieldName);
            }
            w.write('\n');
            headerRow++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < schema.getFieldCount(); j++) {
            try {
                if (j > 0) {
                    w.write(CSV_DELIMITER);
                }
                Type fieldType = g.getType().getType(j);
                PrimitiveType pt = (PrimitiveType) g.getType().getFields().get(j);
                int valueCount = g.getFieldRepetitionCount(j);
                String valueToString = g.getValueToString(j, 0);
                if (pt.getPrimitiveTypeName().name().equals("INT96")) {
                    for (int index = 0; index < valueCount; index++) {
                        if (fieldType.isPrimitive()) {
                            LocalDateTime dateTime = convertToDate(g.getInt96(j, index).getBytes());
                            valueToString = String.valueOf(dateTime);
                        }
                    }
                }
                w.write(valueToString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                w.write("");
                continue;
            }
        }
        w.write('\n');
    }


// Method to convert INT96 value to LocalDateTime.
    private static LocalDateTime convertToDate(byte[] int96Bytes) {
        // Find Julian day
        int julianDay = 0;
        int index = int96Bytes.length;
        while (index > 8) {
            index--;
            julianDay <<= 8;
            julianDay += int96Bytes[index] & 0xFF;
        }

        // Find nanos since midday (since Julian days start at midday)
        long nanos = 0;
        // Continue from the index we got to
        while (index > 0) {
            index--;
            nanos <<= 8;
            nanos += int96Bytes[index] & 0xFF;
        }

        LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDate.MIN
                .with(JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY, julianDay)
                .atTime(LocalTime.NOON)
                .plusNanos(nanos);
        System.out.println("Timestamp: " + timestamp);
        return timestamp;
    }

}
```

Here I am downloading entire file to local system, if the size of parquet file is big this solution is not scalable. Downloading full file is not useful for me.

Is there any way to read parquet file directly from InputStream? Instead of downloading it to local and reading a local file.

Comment: Thats good way, but I also need to read files from sftp server.

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution for it? or Downloading full file and reading it is the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can download a row group from server and parse it later.